# Import-csv with delimiter "\" then store 3rd part of each line in a variable

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to import a file using the delimiter `\` and store the 3rd part of each line in a variable.

```
$a = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`\" -Path c:\fso\mytabfile.tsv
```

above command delete everything after \ but my requirement to delemit using \ and then store only 3rd in a variable

below is the file content:

```
hello\tree\one\four
hello\chair\two\four
hi\tree\three\four
```

Expected output:

```
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `-split` command if your file doesn't have CSV headers.

```
$Variable = Get-Content '.\file.config' | % {
    ($_ -split '\\')[2]
}
$Variable

one
two
three
```

Comment: `$_.Split("\")` would also work here and you would not have to worry about escaping regex meta characters.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import-csv "c:\fso\mytabfile.tsv" -Delimiter '\' -Header Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 | select Col3
```